# Fantasy novel from the 80s, quest led back home

Tags: story-identification

Read this book in my religious high school's library back in the 80s. It was a book about a young man who goes off on a fantasy quest, only to realize that the answer to everything was right back at home where he started, in the holy book of his family. Not exactly an appealing narrative structure :) But I'm curious to find it, if someone else knows the title/author...

Comment: The story of the boy going on a quest only to realize what he was looking for is Paulo Coelho's *The Alchemist*, but that wasn't fantasy and is about an actual treasure, not a book.

Comment: Unfortunately, way too generic a plotline. Any names, animal sidekicks, magic weapons, other races? Remember what the cover looked like?